# Access 2000 VBA - Dir() Bad File Name Or Number

Tags: ms-access, vba, directory

I have a scenario where a user who is not on the domain is trying to open a file that is on the network. Trying to determine if the path exists using the Dir() function. Here is what my code looks like...

```
If Len(Dir("\\xx\xxxxx\Shared\Virtual Machine\_Testing\Update\", vbDirectory)) > 0 Then Return True
```

I get the Run-Time error Bad file name or number (error number 52).

Comment: In this case, I think you would be better off with the FileSystemObject - VBScript is very similar to VBA http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch28h2s7(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, `dir()` on a bad/inaccessible unc causes a runtime error, unlike the behaviour for a local file.

You can either wrap it in an error handler or use the `GetFileAttributes` API and look for the directory attribute flag (the built in getattr() won't work for this).

Answer (score 0):

For the time-being, if the user doesn't mind [mapping a network drive](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdcXlrm9cyk), he could open the file with your code the way it is.

Answer (score -1):

Try below steps.

- Restart your machine
- After restart, access/open the share path through windows explorer
- Provide the network credentials and select the option "remember my
  credentials"

Now run/debug your application. it should work!